# Changing Fancy Sliding Form active tab on page load

Tags: jquery

I am using Fancy Sliding Form.
(Source website: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/06/07/fancy-sliding-form-with-jquery/
Demo: http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/FancySlidingForm/)

I put a popup window in my second tab, there I made a postback to save my inputs from popup window but when I do this, the page refreshes and I lose the current active tab, it goes to the first tab.

I see in the js file:

```
    /*  current position of fieldset / navigation link    */
var current     = 1;
```

But how can I change the beginning tab. I want activate another tab on page load.

Comment: what is your server side language ?

Comment: ASP.NET  c# ,i have no problem calling Javascript from serverside, just need the proper javascript to set the active_tab to another number like 2

Comment: you have to set the javascript variable from c# as I mention in answer. but answer has php code, just change it to your language.

Answer (score 0):

you can set javascript variable as bellow and use it for your script.

sample code with php ,

```
<?php 
    $active_tab_from_php = 2 // you should change this, for testing you can hard code
    echo '<script> var active_tab = "'. $active_tab_from_php . '";</script>';
?>
```

now you can use this `active_tab` variable with your script as below,

```
var current    = active_tab;
```

Comment: the jquery file does not accept any parameter, that was actually my problem, i need to find a way to inject a variable to that jquery function. it starts like this   $(function() {
    /*
    number of fieldsets
    */
    var fieldsetCount = $('#formElem').children().length;
 
    /*
    current position of fieldset / navigation link
    */
    var current     = 1;

Comment: you don't want to pass it like a parameter, just initialize before you are import your javascript from the server side as I mention in the answer.

Comment: it's not about jquery, its about javascript variable scope. initialize the javascript variable from the server side code before import you js file (for fancy tab).

Comment: or else just assign your value to hidden variable and read it from jquery.